# Functions approximated by rolling epicycle curves

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, approximation-theory, curves-and-surfaces, classical-mechanics

Imagine a decreasing sequence of (positive) radii $r_1 > r_2 > r_3 > \cdots$
and a series of nested circles $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \supset \cdots$
with these radii,
initially each resting on
the $x$-axis tangent at $(0,0)$.
Each is assigned a rolling speed $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$,
the amount of arc length that $C_i$ rolls on the inside of $C_{i-1}$
per unit time.
(Positive $s_i$ represents clockwise spinning of $C_i$; negative, counterclockwise.) 
$C_1$ rolls on the $x$-axis, which can be considered $C_0$.

Here is an example, with $(r_1, r_2, r_3)=(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4})$
and $(s_1, s_2, s_3)=(1,2,3)$, with the track of a point on
the third circle highlighted:

[image]

Call the curve that is the track of the $n$-th circle
a *rolling epicycle curve*, or just a *rolling curve*.
My question is:

> **Q1.**
>   What is the class of functions on some interval $[0,X]$
>   that can be approximated by some rolling curve?

Say that a function $f(x)$ is *approximated* by a rolling curve
if, for any $\epsilon > 0$, a curve may be found
that remains within an $\epsilon$-tube around $f$.
(One can easily substitute other reasonable definitions of
approximation.)
To be specific, we could insist that $f(0)=0$ and the rolling
curve tracks the innermost circle's point that initially
touches $(0,0)$.

Here is a more random example of four circles of
radii $(1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2})$, with
green tracking the fourth circle:

[image]

There is considerable flexibility, but it seems difficult
to control.  To pose a more specific version of Q1:

> **Q2.**
>   Can a straight line through $(0,0)$ be approximated on a given
>   interval $[0,X]$?

Wondering about the power of Ptolemaic epicycles led me to
this question (although I realize the rolling constraint
renders my question different). Thanks for insights!

**Addendum.** As per J.M.'s request, here is an animated GIF for
the three-circle example (which may or may not animate, depending on your browser settings):

         [image: a3 animation]

Comment: Very interesting! By any chance, did you make animations of these?

Comment: @J.M.: No, but I should!  When I get a chance...

Comment: In Q1, it might be necessary for f(x) to have derivative 0 at the origin.  (It looks so from the figure, but I do not know if it is true.)  If this is true, then the answer to Q2 will be clearly No.

Comment: In the animation, is the smallest circle necessary?

Comment: By the way, the cycloid itself has no derivative at the origin, and the right-sided derivative is infinite, not $0$, so it's not a necessary condition to be approximated that a function have derivative $0$ at the origin.

Comment: Also, approximation within $\epsilon$ does not require matching derivative.

Comment: @Douglas: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by "is the smallest circle necessary"...

Comment: I think Douglas Zare's question is about the fact that the path you delineate traces the point of contact between the smallest curve and the middle curve, rather than the trajectory of a chosen point on the smallest curve.  This may have something to do with the fact that the radii that you draw make the largest circle appear to roll, and the smaller circles appear to slide.

Comment: @Scott & Douglas: Oh, I see!  Yes, indeed I inadvertently tracked the point of contact between the smallest circle and the one in which it rolls, as opposed to an arbitrary point on the smallest circle.  Cannot fix the computations now...

Comment: Fixed the computation: Changed a single $\lt$ to $\le$ in the code! :-/

Comment: @Douglas: Thanks, your comment (together with the new figures) renders my previous comment completely pointless.

Comment: Incidentally, it is easy to get one straight line exactly: $y=0$! This can be achieved by two circles with the inner one rolling exactly
at the same arc-length-per-unit-time speed as the outer one.

Comment: The curves which can be approximated by rolling are not different from the curves which can be approximated by sliding since you can add an $n+1$st innermost microscopic circle whose rolling approximates any rotation speed of the $n$th circle. 

Comment: If some curve has a nonzero finite slope at the origin, then you can approximate a line with that slope by rescaling. However, $y(t)$ is an even power series in $t$ while $x(t)$ is an odd power series, and  they can't have a nonzero finite ratio as $t \to 0$. This doesn't rule out the possibility of approximating a line other than a vertical or horizontal one, but it will be much more complicated if it is possible.

Comment: @Douglas: Cool idea to look at power-series parity!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke what was the function you used for the animation?

Comment: @Lupus: I used Mathematica, `ListAnimate[]`.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I mean mathematical formulation of the diagram I'm not an expert on math consepts :).